# How to make WordCount use new Java libraries in Cloudera?

Tags: java, hadoop, jar, cloudera, word-count

I am new to Hadoop, and trying the example of WordCount V1.0 here:

https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/other/tutorial/CDH5/topics/ht_usage.html

However, when I compile the WordCount.java using this line:

```
javac -cp /usr/lib/hadoop/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/* WordCount.java -d build -Xlint
```

It seems like the code uses the old version of .jar files, and gives me the following warnings (as shown in the picture). However, when I check inside the classpath I declared, there are some .jar files which seems to be newer versions of those being required .jar files.
[image]

So my question is that how can I make my WordCount.java use the newer file instead? I tried looking inside the WordCount.java code to see which rows use those required .jar files but could not see them.
Thanks in advance for any help.

The code of the WordCount.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.IntWritable;
import org.apache.hadoop.io.Text;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Reducer;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat;
import org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.FileOutputFormat;

public class WordCount {

  public static class TokenizerMapper
       extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

    private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
    private Text word = new Text();

    public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context
                    ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
      while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
        word.set(itr.nextToken());
        context.write(word, one);
      }
    }
  }

  public static class IntSumReducer
       extends Reducer<Text,IntWritable,Text,IntWritable> {
    private IntWritable result = new IntWritable();

    public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                       Context context
                       ) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
      int sum = 0;
      for (IntWritable val : values) {
        sum += val.get();
      }
      result.set(sum);
      context.write(key, result);
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    Job job = Job.getInstance(conf, "word count");
    job.setJarByClass(WordCount.class);
    job.setMapperClass(TokenizerMapper.class);
    job.setCombinerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setReducerClass(IntSumReducer.class);
    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
    FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(args[0]));
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's just a warning. Does the code work?

Comment: Yes, if I move on to run the next code in the tutorial, it still works. However, give me the following warning lines:

>>>>>>cloudera@quickstart ~]$ hadoop jar wordcount.jar WordCount /user/cloudera/wordcount/input /user/cloudera/wordcount/output
>>>>>>16/11/12 22:27:44 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
>>>>>>16/11/12 22:27:46 WARN mapreduce.JobResourceUploader: Hadoop command-line option parsing not performed. Implement the Tool interface and execute your application with ToolRunner to remedy this.

Comment: That's a standard Hadoop issue. [Read from here](https://hadoopi.wordpress.com/2013/06/05/hadoop-implementing-the-tool-interface-for-mapreduce-driver/)

Comment: Oh I see, thank you so much for your hint. Do you think that these warnings will affect the result of Hadoop MapReduce, and future code? Because I will have to develop this code further.

Comment: As long as you follow the ToolRunner interface, you should be fine. Otherwise, writing pure MapReduce Java code has gone away for several years now. Apache Spark can do word count in literally one line....